# Does Objective-C have garbage collector on the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, garbage-collection

I'm thinking of writing an app for the iphone. But I'm confused in regards to the objective-c language. Am I correct in saying that I have to do my own memory management? Is Objective-C a managed language such as C# and/or Java?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Managed" is a marketing term that has no technical meaning. Objective C for the iPhone is not garbage collected, but uses retain counting memory management. So in some sense, you have to do your own memory management, but it's limited to knowing the [Cocoa retain counting methodology](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Edit: My comments on "managed" refer to a [previous post version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2617932/revisions). The comment is left here because I'm tired of seeing the word.

Answer (score 5):

There is no garbage collection feature. However, any object you `copy`, `retain`, `alloc` etc. has its retain count bumped up by one, and you are responsible for calling a `release`or an `autorelease` - you own an instance of that object. If you don't call `[<YOUROBJECT> release];` or `[<YOUROBJECT> autorelease];`, the object remains in the iPhone's/iPod Touch's/iPad's memory, but the pointer no longer remains, and a memory leak occurs, as that bit of memory can no longer be accessed. Autoreleasing adds the object to the autorelease pool, and means that it will become released at some point in the future. Always use a standard `release` where possible, as `autorelease` means that it will still stay in the device's memory for a while, you can never be sure when it will be released, and it is a slightly more demanding method to call.

Never call `dealloc` on an object - releasing or autoreleasing is sufficient, and if required, the object will automatically be dealloced.

Make sure you never release objects you do not own, and if you do release objects, you release them after you no longer have any use of them - otherwise, you may try to access that object, and the device cannot find the object, and the situation results in your app crashing due to an `EXEC_BAC_ACCESS` error - to find out the root of the problem, open Instruments, add the Object Allocation instrument and enable NSZombie detection in its preferences (or add the Zombies instrument (only available in iPhone SDK 3.2+)). You can then view the entire history of the object which causes the problem, and jump to the exact line of code that caused the problem.

You can read more [here](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html).

Hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

You have to do your own memory management with [Objective-C on the iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out Objective-C has no garbage collector on the iPhone, but it does have one for Mac OSX. Here is an article describing this in more detail: http://vasudevkamath.blogspot.com/2010/01/objective-c-my-opinions.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer isn't specific to Objective-C. If you're doing iPhone development, no...there is no garbage collector. If you're developing for Mac OSX, however, there is garbage collection.