# Which is easier to learn coming from a C# background: Objective C or Java?

Tags: c#, java, iphone, android, objective-c

I've used C# quite a lot, it was my main programming language during University and I wondered which of the two languages for developing for Android or iPhone are easiest to learn bearing that in mind.

I'm interested in people's opinions on the two languages, I've dabbled a little in both but nothing more than a couple of hours. I'm also interested in people's opinions on Windows Phone 7 as an app/game platform, as this uses C# so would be an obvious choice for transitioning into that area.

Opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of language will depend on your motives.  If you intend to write commercial software that you want to sell, it's probably best to go for Objective-C and aim at the iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad.  Objective-C is a steeper learning curve for a C# programmer than Java but that is as nothing compared with actually thinking up an app that people will want to buy and getting it to commercial quality.  And people who own iDevices are still more numerous than people with Android devices and they probably have more expectation of having to pay for apps.

If you are doing it as a hobby then you will want to choose whichever platform your current smartphone/tablet or whatever supports. You are going to be the primary user of your apps.  It makes sense to develop apps that you can use.  Another consideration, if you are a hobbyist:  to develop an iPhone app you need an Intel Macintosh and a $99 Apple electronic certificate to deploy apps to an iPhone even for testing.

The actual language is a relatively minor consideration.  A reasonably competent programmer can pick up Objective-C in a couple of weeks.  The frameworks will take a little longer, but if you are doing it as a learning experience, it will be a more rewarding experience than learning Java which is nearly the same as C# by comparison.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer! Seeing as I currently have an Android device and a Windows machine, it makes much more sense for me to develop for Android. If money wasn't a factor I think Objective-C would definitely be the way to go. Do you have an opinion on developing for WP7 at all? I'd be interested to hear what you have to say.

Comment: @Zachary Markham: I'm sceptical about WP7's ability to get market penetration.  However, I also thought the iPhone would never sell, the iPad was too expensive and nobody would want a music player with a touch screen.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Haha I'm also skeptical about WP7, but down to Microsofts poor track record with mobile devices rather than the products themselves.

Answer (score 6):

That would be [Java](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html) but you will [miss LINQ](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/02/01/c-vs-java-part-1-the-languages/) a lot.

You can develop in C# for the iPhone with [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) but it's not free and you'll never know if Apple sends them out in the cold (unlikely). Soon you can even use C# for Android development with [MonoDroid](http://monodroid.net/) but I kind of feel that that's a smaller win for a C# programmer than not having to learn Objective-C. Java and C# are so close that the transition most probably will be smooth.

As a C# programmer I think that the Windows Phone 7 development platform looks very promising but my experience tells me to wait and see. Microsoft has a terrible track record in the mobile business and they also have a tendency to make big changes between early releases.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking with WP7 as stated in above comment. It has potential to do really well but like you said Microsoft and Mobile just don't seem to get on. However being an early developer for the platform could lead you to releasing the first big thing for the platform!

Comment: I was going to down vote you for the comment about Mono Touch not being free (I thought it was open source) but I decided to check my facts first and was amazed to find that it is not free and in fact, it is quite expensive.

Comment: Yep, $400 minimum :( There is a trial although I'm not sure how much it allows you to do.

Comment: @Kendall Now I've read up on NSPredicate and I beg to differ. There are some similarities but NSPredicate is a very different beast. It's not a part of the language like LINQ and the syntax is extremely verbose in some extent because there are no inferred typing.

Comment: Can you give an example (or point to a web page with an example) where inferred typing is useful where the generic id typing of NSPredicate and KVC would not be able to work?  It is more verbose but so is the whole language...

Comment: See the comment by thsutton at http://www.cimgf.com/2008/08/24/cocoa-tutorial-c-linq-or-cocoa-key-paths-and-nspredicate/

Answer (score 4):

Java I think.  The semantic model for C# is closer, and ObjectiveC for iPhone apparently is [not garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617932/does-objective-c-have-garbage-collector-on-the-iphone).  You will probably miss some of the features of C#, but most people get over it.

Comment: What kind of features do you miss out on? While dabbling with Objective C I noticed the lack of garbage collection and it was pretty infuriating!

Answer (score 2):

I have a co-worker who made an attempt to learn Objective C to do I-phone development.  We are both .Net developers working mostly in C#.  He had a very long learning curve and finally abandoned trying to learn Objective C not only because of the language barrier but also because of the setup.  Coming from a C# background, expect a long haul getting your arms around Objective C.  Java on the other hand is more like C# and might be better to start with.  I am in the same boat as you and actually decided on Windows Phone 7 development first because it is C#.  I would go after the droid market next as I think it would be easier to learn.

Comment: I've been thinking about WP7 development but I just know whether the platform will take off as well as the others. If it has the same kind of impact as Android and is as well supported then I can imagine it being great to develop for!

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been said before, I figured I would point out a fact, C# came about because of the law suit surrouding Microsoft's Java Virtual Machine.  I would describe C# as the son of Java and C++, at least in early versions.  C# 4.0 has added features neither of them have, its really matured into its own language.

So if you come from a C# background then you should be able to pick up Java effortlessly.  Of course Objective-C is C++ on crack, so it should still be possible, what you will miss is Visual Studio and all the features it brings.  The reason C# is so easy to develop for is all the features in Visual Studio and most of the features of the language are supported.

Comment: Are there any particularly friendly environments for developing with Java that you'd personally recommend? It seems that the general consensus is that Eclipse reigns supreme in this field. Are there any other great ones that have been overshadowed?

Comment: Objective-C is less like C++ than Java or C#.  It's certainly no C++ on crack.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is also a great IDE for Java. It's a commercial product, but has both free and paid versions. Specific to Android development: both IDEA and Eclipse have good Android development support - though you will probably find more materials covering Android development in Eclipse; the Android team supplies the Eclipse plugin for Android development.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, C# is partially based on Java, so that step would be a lot easier. 
I'm also familiar with Java, C# and ObjC and started out with C#, then did Java and now use Objective-C..

And the C# -> Java part was because my education did it that way.. ;-)

And because WEBAPPS are a thing that is HOT right now.. i would say.. Java is a safer choice, because you could base a webapp on that.. although ObjC might also have those possibilities, i just don't know about it..

[image]

Comment: That images hurts my brain lol. I certainly think that having Java in my repertoire would be more beneficial than Objective C and potentially has more future use!

Answer (score 1):

I switched from C# to Java because I needed to code a lot of systems integration. C# was just not powerful enough / limited to .NET systems. I agree that LINQ is a nice feature, and that generics in C# are a lot more straightforward, but if you start looking at the whole Java ecosystem, I guess these are just minor losses.

Just to sum up some great things you get when switching to Java: Eclipse IDE, maven build system, Spring dependency injection and aspect oriented programming framework + OSGi, GlassFish application server, Grizzly, Jetty, Hadoop, the apache commons libraries, ... . All these things come in Java, and are very useful when you start programming services.

I don't know about Objective-C

Hope this helps,
J.

Comment: Have you used any IDE's other than Eclipse? Or is Eclipse really the Visual Studio equivalent for Java?

Comment: @Zachary - I have not heard of anything besides Eclipse but I also have very limited exposer to Java. I would warn you the limited introduction I had to Eclipse I was underwhelmed to say the least. Of course I used it for an entirely different purpose ( was attempting to write something in JavaScript ) I was under whelmed.  I just now looked up IntelliJ IDEA and just realized its from the same guys as ReSharper which I have found to be of excellent quality.

Comment: C# isn't just for Windows. There is Mono, a virtual machine not made by MS, that can run on windows,linux,android, and runs BCIL/.NET bytecode so C#.  Tried it in Windows, you type mono blah.exe<ENTER> and it runs it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using MonoTouch?

Comment: I've had a read around the subject but while I'm new in the area I don't want to be using costly software. I'm not thinking about developing anything massively commercial atm, more of a hobby really, and it'd also give me an opportunity for me to learn a new language!